# Multidimensional Array with json_decode

Tags: arrays, json, api

This is what I get from an API:

```
{
     "isFeiertag":"1",
     "datum":"25.12.2014",
     "title":"1. Weihnachtstag",
     "locs":["BW","BY","BE","BB","HB","HH","HE","MV","NI","NW","RP","SL","SN","ST","SH","TH"]
    }
```

This is my PHP:

```
$url = 'APIURL';
$feiertagejson = file_get_contents($url); 
$feiertagejson = utf8_encode($feiertagejson); 
$results = json_decode($feiertagejson, true);
if($results['isFeiertag'] = '0'){
    echo "kein Feiertag";
}else{
    echo "Heute ist ".$results['datum']." > ".$results['title']." in ".$results['locs'].".";
}
```

How can I get the "locs"?

This is what I get actually:

Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\xampp\htdocs\explode.php on line 18
Heute ist 25.12.2014 > 1. Weihnachtstag in Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [implode](http://php.net/implode) to convert the array to string

```
implode(",",$results['locs']);
```

change the echo line as below

```
echo "Heute ist ".$results['datum']." > ".$results['title']." in ".implode(",",$results['locs']).".";
```